# Checking consistency of multiple arguments using Mockito

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I'm using Mockito to mock a class that has a method that looks something like this:

```
setFoo(int offset, float[] floats)
```

I want to be able verify that the values in the array (`floats`) are equal (within a given tolerance) to values in an array of expected values.

The catch is that I want to check the contents of `floats` starting at the position specified by `offset`. For the purposes of the test I don't know/care what the offset is as long as it points at the values I'm expecting. I also don't care what the rest of the array contains. I only care about the values starting at the supplied offset.

How do I do this?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I don't quite understand your question. What's the problem with writing your own method that takes offset and 2 arrays as arguments and checks that elements in these arrays starting from offset are equal?

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov how do I "write my own method" on a Mockito mock object?

Comment: I don't think you even should. After calling `setFoo()` you expect that object's state has changed. So you should query the state of the object and compare it with your values. Some code snippet would be useful to understand the problem better.

Comment: The class that's being mocked deals with hardware. There is no corresponding "get" for this "set" method. That's why I'm mocking it out.

Comment: it would be easier to help with some code to look at.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

While a partial mock isn't a bad idea, you might find your code easier to follow if you use an [ArgumentCaptor](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) instead to get the values after the fact. It's a special argument matcher that keeps track of the value it matches.

```
// initialized with MockitoAnnotations.initMocks();
@Captor ArgumentCaptor<Integer> offsetCaptor;
@Captor ArgumentCaptor<float[]> floatsCaptor;
@Mock Bar bar;

@Test
public void valuesShouldBeCloseEnough() {
  Sut sut = new Sut(bar);
  sut.doSomething();
  verify(bar).setFoo(offsetCaptor.capture(), floatsCaptor.capture());

  // check values with assertValuesAreCloseEnough, declared elsewhere
  assertValuesAreCloseEnough(offsetCaptor.getValue(), floatsCaptor.getValue());
}
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want a [partial mock](http://marcschwieterman.com/blog/simple-stub-creation-with-mockito-partial-mocks/). Let's assume that the class that has `setFoo()` is named Bar:

```
private static abstract class AssertingBar implements Bar {

  @Override
  void setFoo(int offset, float[] floats) {
    this.offset = offset;
    this.floats = floats
  }

  public void verify(float[] expectedFloats, float delta) {
    // do your verification here
  }
}

@Test
public void valuesShouldBeCloseEnough() {
  AssertingBar bar = Mockito.mock(AssertingBar.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);

  Sut sut = new Sut(bar);
  sut.doSomething();

  bar.verify(...); 
}
```

If `Bar` is a class, not an interface, then you can use `doCallRealMethod()`

Comment: `Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS` didn't seem to work with an interface. I was constantly getting errors about trying to call a real method on an interface. I was making some progress with `doCallRealMethod()`, but the argument captor approach suggested in another answer was easier to get working, and required a lot less code for this particular case. Thanks anyway.